# How to find the set of parameters that gives the optimal value from a function in r

Tags: r, optimization

```
##' param1 a numeric from 0 to 1
##' param2 a numeric from 1 to 100
##' param3 a binary TRUE or FALSE variable
return_number <- function(param1, param2, param3) {
  # computes some number based on parameters
  # returns it
}
```

What can I use in R to find the set of parameters that yields the global optimal of the function above?

The function is not analytical. It computes the output by searching a through a data set using a set of rules that are determined by the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for non-linear equation solving:

```
library(nleqslv)

nleqslv()
```

Answer (score 1):

There is more than one way of doing this.
Recently I used the `nloptr` package for optimization. 
In your case, since one parameter can only take two values (`TRUE`, `FALSE`) you can do two searches and simply compare the results:

Here is one possibility to do a global search  for optimal parameters:

```
library(nloptr)

res1 <- nloptr(x = c(1/2, 50), #starting value 
               eval_f = function(x, y) return_number(x, y, TRUE), #function to be minimized
               lb = c(0, 1), #lower bound
               ub = c(1, 100), #upper bound
               opts = list("algorithm" = "NLOPT_GN_CRS2_LM", #specify the algorithm
                           "ftol_abs" = 1e-6, "xtol_rel" = 1e-5, #additional parameters
                            "ranseed" = 4131, "maxeval" = 1e5)) 

res2 <- nloptr(x = c(1/2, 50), #starting value 
               eval_f = function(x, y) return_number(x, y, FALSE), #function to be minimized
               lb = c(0, 1), #lower bound
               ub = c(1, 100), #upper bound
               opts = list("algorithm" = "NLOPT_GN_CRS2_LM", #specify the algorithm
                           "ftol_abs" = 1e-6, "xtol_rel" = 1e-5, #additional parameters
                            "ranseed" = 4131, "maxeval" = 1e5))
```

You can find additional details on how to use `nloptr` on [this webpage](https://nlopt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: What does it mean to "minimize the function"? I meant to find the set of parameters where the function is at the maximum. What do I need to change above?

Comment: in order to minimize you can simply put a minus in front of the function (i,e) `- f`instead of `f`.

Comment: Error in .checkfunargs(eval_f, arglist, "eval_f") : 
  eval_f requires argument 'y' but this has not been passed to the 'nloptr' function. This is the error that I am getting

Comment: hard to tell without knowing your exact function

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use [`fmincon` from package `pracma`](https://rdrr.io/cran/pracma/man/fmincon.html), which aims to

> Find minimum of multivariable functions with nonlinear constraints

```
pracma::fmincon()
```

Below is an example to apply it maybe for your case

```
x0 <- c(param1,param2,param3)
lb0 <- c(0,1,0)
ub0 <- c(1,100,1)
heq0 <- function(x) x%%1

pracma::fmincon(x0,return_number,lb = lb0, ub = ub0, heq = heq0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have only three parameters, a grid search might work for your problem. Implemented for instance in function `gridSearch` in package [`NMOF`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=NMOF)  (which I maintain).  If that won't do, you could try a local search; see this [tutorial](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3391756).